# Cannot open PDF file on Windows 8 when Reader app is set default C#

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8

My app have a web app and a desktop app. Web app can invoke desktop app through a custom protocol (name such as `MyProtocol://OpenFile:abc.pdf`). When the web app require open a file on desktop, it invoke desktop app with a special command. Then desktop app (C# language) open the file with Process.Start("abc.pdf") command.

It works perfectly with another file types (image, office document, audio...), but on some machine, it cannot open PDF file when `Reader app` on Windows 8 is set default for viewing PDF file type. It works when another PDF viewer tools (Foxit or Adobe reader) has installed and set as default viewer for PDF. I've tried open a PDF file directly, without calling from web through custom protocol, and it worked properly.

I don't known any security or what problem there, because the command `Process.Start()` does not throw any exception.

Anybody help me solve this problem. Or how to invoke Reader app with a special argument to open PDF file? Thanks.